# Cannnot resolve symbol "OnClickListener"

Tags: android

The following code shows error of Cannot resolve symbol "**ÖnClickListener**", expecting ";" and Method onClick(android.view.view) never used. 
Classes which are imported.
Below is the my code that will helpful to find the exception.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import .Variables;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements onClickListener (Says Cannnot resolve symbol OnClickListener) {
      //Initialize variables
      Variables
      var;


      // Main Program starts here-------------------------------------------------
      @
      Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          //Initiate spinners and adapters here
          var.spin_hv = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_hv);
          var.adapt = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.str_hv, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
          var.adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          var.spin_hv.setAdapter(var.adapt);

          // Method called after Spinner is selected from the menu
          var.spin_hv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {@
              Override
              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (var.dbug) {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Transfer the selection into a variable to be used in calculation
                var.hv_string = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                //Check for which type of heating value unit of measurement is selected
                if (var.hv_string.equals("kCal/m3")) {
                  var.lhv_flag = 1;
                }
                if (var.hv_string.equals("btu/ft3")) {
                  var.lhv_flag = 2;
                } else
                  var.lhv_flag = 3;

              }

              @
              Override
              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > parent) {

              }
            }_______________error ")" expected



Error here as ";" & "}" expected

            public void onClick(View v) {
              switch (v.getId()) {
                case (R.id.but_calc):
                  butCalculateClick(v);
                  break;
              }

            }


          }   'error class or interface expected'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception is not due to the `OnClickListener`.
It is due to the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` method just add `)};` at the end of the method definition.

```
var.spin_hv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {@
              Override
              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (var.dbug) {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Transfer the selection into a variable to be used in calculation
                var.hv_string = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                //Check for which type of heating value unit of measurement is selected
                if (var.hv_string.equals("kCal/m3")) {
                  var.lhv_flag = 1;
                }
                if (var.hv_string.equals("btu/ft3")) {
                  var.lhv_flag = 2;
                } else
                  var.lhv_flag = 3;

              }

              @
              Override
              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > parent) {

              }
            });
```

This code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

use following code to get listener from spinner.

```
var.spin_hv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

---

you implimented onClickListener , but you should use OnClickListener, there is a silly spelling mistake..

do not forget to call view.setOnClickListener(this); in your onCreate. here view is anything like button, text, imageView on which you want to add lisenter.